# Python doesn't work in atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I installed atom to work with Python (Win7 64), then added some packages:
Linter + Language Python + Linter Python Pep8 + Script.
Wrote simple code, that work in IDLE:

```
print ("Hello World")
print (355-325)
i=0
while i<5:

    print(i)
    i=i+1

i=100
```

Runned script, then I have an error:

> "python" �� ����� ����७��� ��� ���譥� ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ���
>   �������� 䠩���. [Finished in 0.063s]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you running the script?  (What is the command you are using)

Comment: I run it from atom I tried with Ctrl+Shift+B (with selected code, and with no selection), and for Packages->Script->Run

Comment: It could be an encoding error with all the garbage it dumped out...what are you saving the file as?

Comment: If you open a fresh command prompt, and type `python` -- what happens?

Comment: Thanks, i add new line into Path, everithing works now))

Answer (score 1):

**System Properties** -> **Advanced** tab -> **Environment Variables...** -> **System Variables** list

Scroll System Variables and find variable "Path", select it, then click Edit. On field **Variable Value** go to end pushing End keyboard button, then append

> ;c:\YourPathToPytonExeDir\

Just dir path with "\" on end. (For example your python.exe in this case must be in c:\YourPathToPytonExeDir\python.exe). Do not forget use ";" as separator for existing data.

P.S. As I see by error, You are using Russian (not English) Win 7 locale. You need just found in google translations of windows options like: System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables... -> System Variables

For test, open cmd and type single C:>**python** command. Must be same return as for C:>**c:\YourPathToPytonExeDir\python.exe**.

**Restart Atom**

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `terminal-plus` package in atom. 
Then get the command palette open (`cmd + shift + p`) and type `terminal`. 
This will open a terminal for you where you can then run your python script.

e.g. `python3 hello_world.py`

Also whilst developing, to speed up your work flow you can install nodemon as an npm package.

e.g. `npm i -g nodemon`

Then run the script through nodemon.

e.g. `nodemon --exec python3 hello_world.py`

This will have the benefit of acting as a watcher which will automatically re-run your program whenever you save a change.

Alternatively there is a script package for atom which can be used instead of terminal-plus however I believe you need to configure your own environment variables for this to work with external modules that require importing.